# What does "crystal ball" mean in the context?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

I just asked [a question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150146/whats-the-youngest-programming-language). They closed it because it needed a "crystal ball" to answer such questions.

My concept of "crystal ball" makes me interpret it as that we need some *magic* to be able to answer. Somehow, I don't feel it is right.

I searched "crystal ball" online, but failed to find any special meaning associated with it. I suspect that it might be related to some popular culture I'm not aware of, so I decide to ask for help here.

Comment: "I searched "crystal ball" online", if that was meant literally, then this Q fits ELL. On the other hand, if it was meant tongue in cheek as it more likely is, then this is a question for meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your SO question:

> By youngest programming language, I mean that the language should have notable influence and **will continue to shape the world**, provided that it appears most recently.

As you want the answerer to know how the programming language will fare *in the future*, s/he will need to use a *crystal ball* to find out.

*[Crystal ball](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crystal%20ball)*:

> 1 : a sphere especially of quartz crystal traditionally **used by fortune-tellers**
>   2 : a means or method of **predicting future events**

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105678/what-does-crystal-ball-mean-in-the-context#comment215370_105678